# python encoding conversion

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-2.6

Here's my problem, I have a variable wrongly encoded that I want to fix. Long story short, I end up with:

```
myVar=u'\xc3\xa9'
```

which is wrong because it's the character 'é' or `\u00e9` UTF-8 encoded, not unicode.

None of the combinations of encode/decode I tried seem to solve the problem. I looked towards the bytearray object, but you must provide an encoding, and obviously none of them fits.

Basically I need to reinterpret the byte array into the correct encoding. Any ideas on how to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: What would you like to end up with, unicode or str?

Comment: @X-Istence : nope unicode is a *number* standing for a character, while UTF-8 is an *encoding* for that number (such as UTF-16, UTF-32 ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should have done.

```
>>> b='\xc3\xa9'
>>> b
'\xc3\xa9'
>>> b.decode("UTF-8")
u'\xe9'
```

Since you didn't show the broken code that caused the problem, all we can do is make a complex problem more complex.

This appears to be what you're seeing.

```
>>> c
u'\xc3\xa9'
>>> c.decode("UTF-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's a workaround.

```
>>> [ chr(ord(x)) for x in c ]
['\xc3', '\xa9']
>>> ''.join(_)
'\xc3\xa9'
>>> _.decode("UTF-8")
u'\xe9'
```

Fix the code that produced the wrong stuff to begin with.

Comment: Yeah I know what should have been done, and that fixing the source of the problem is the best solution. But I'm in a situation where I can't, so I'll take the workaroud, which is precisely what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: It appears that `c.encode('iso-8859-15').decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')` works too. Am I in a special case?

Comment: @gregseth: No.  Many encodings overlap.  The point of UTF-8 is to look vaguely like ASCII for most of the standard ASCII characters.  I have no idea what you mean by "works" in that comment, since there's no point in doing a decode to create Unicode followed by and encode to recreate the bytes again.  Python code works in Unicode.  Period.  External files are encoded (on output) and decoded (on input).   There's no other use for encoding and decoding except file I/O.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I got confused. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The hacky solution: pull out the codepoints with `ord`, then build characters (length-one strings) out of these with `chr`, then paste the lot back together and decode.

```
>>> u = u'\xc3\xa9'
>>> s = ''.join(chr(ord(c)) for c in u)
>>> unicode(s, encoding='utf-8')
u'\xe9'
```